# Fortran coding for the density of states of linear lattice

Tags: fortran

The written code contains some errors.  I am using Visual Studio 2012 and the Intel.Visual.Fortran.Composer.XE.2013.0.089 compiler.

This is the code I wrote

```
PROGRAM DensityOfState
 
IMPLICIT NONE

INTEGER :: omega , t0 , a0 ,kx

omega=1 ; t0 =1 ; a0=1

REAL :: kx  , eta , w , ek

 eta=0.0015

 REAL,PARAMETER :: pi=3.14

COMPLEX , PARAMETER ::i=(0,1)

COMPLEX :: Energy 

COMPLEX :: Density

COMPLEX :: GreenFunc

LoopEnergy : DO w=-2,+2,0.001

   WRITE(*,*)  Energy= w +( i * eta)

LoopWaveVector : DO kx=-1000,1000
 WRITE(*,*)    ek= 2*t0*COS(kx*a0)

   WRITE(*,*)  GreenFunc= Energy - ek

END DO LoopEnergy

END DO LoopWaveVector

WRITE(*,*) IMAG(GreenFunc)

Density= (1.0/pi*omega)*IMAG(GreenFunc)

 WRITE(*,*) Density

 END PROGRAM DensityOfState
```

And this is a list of errors

```
Error   1    error #5082: Syntax error, found IDENTIFIER 'ENERGY' when expecting one of: ( % [ . = 

1>------ Build started: Project: Console3, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------

1>Compiling with Intel(R) Visual Fortran Compiler XE 13.0.0.089 [IA-32]...

1>Source1.f90

 error #5082: Syntax error, found IDENTIFIER 'ENERGY' when expecting one of: ( % [ . = =>

 error #5082: Syntax error, found IDENTIFIER 'EK' when expecting one of: ( % [ . = =>

 error #5082: Syntax error, found IDENTIFIER 'GREENFUNC' when expecting one of: ( % [ . = =>

 error #6236: A specification statement cannot appear in the executable section.

 error #6236: A specification statement cannot appear in the executable section.

 error #6236: A specification statement cannot appear in the executable section.

 error #6236: A specification statement cannot appear in the executable section.

 error #6236: A specification statement cannot appear in the executable section.

 error #6236: A specification statement cannot appear in the executable section.

 error #6404: This name does not have a type, and must have an explicit type.   [ETA]

 error #6404: This name does not have a type, and must have an explicit type.   [W]

 error #6063: An INTEGER or REAL data type is required in this context.   [W]

 warning #6041: The increment in a DO is zero or evaluates to zero.   [0.001]

 error #6458: This name must be the name of a variable with a derived type (structure type)   [WRITE]


 error #6404: This name does not have a type, and must have an explicit type.   [I]

 error #6458: This name must be the name of a variable with a derived type (structure type)   [WRITE]

 warning #7319: This argument's data type is incompatible with this intrinsic procedure; procedure assumed EXTERNAL.   [COS]

1 error #6404: This name does not have a type, and must have an explicit type.   [COS]

 error #6458: This name must be the name of a variable with a derived type (structure type)   [WRITE]

 error #6404: This name does not have a type, and must have an explicit type.   [ENERGY]

 error #6404: This name does not have a type, and must have an explicit type.   [EK]

 error #6606: The block construct names must match, and they do not.   [LOOPENERGY]

 error #6606: The block construct names must match, and they do not.   [LOOPWAVEVECTOR]

 error #6404: This name does not have a type, and must have an explicit type.   [GREENFUNC]

 warning #7319: This argument's data type is incompatible with this intrinsic procedure; procedure assumed EXTERNAL.   [IMAG]

 error #6404: This name does not have a type, and must have an explicit type.   [IMAG]

 error #6404: This name does not have a type, and must have an explicit type.   [DENSITY]

 error #6404: This name does not have a type, and must have an explicit type.   [PI]

1>compilation aborted for c:\users\mahdi\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Console3\Console3\Source1.f90 (code 1)
```

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Please use correct formatting for the code in your questions and use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions.

Answer (score -1):

```
   WRITE(*,*)  Energy= w +( i * eta)
```

is not a correct Fortran statement. To assign `w +( i * eta)` to `Energy`, use just

```
   Energy= w +( i * eta)
```

To print the value of `Energy`, do just

```
   WRITE(*,*)  Energy
```

Comment: thank you so much.Errors have been fixed.